# Открытие и считывание файла

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы

При вот таком вот способе открытия файла выдает ошибку следующего характера: (фото 1 и фото 2). Как можно исправить? Спасибо

```
CFileDialog fileopen(TRUE);
int result = fileopen.DoModal();
if (result == IDOK) {
    CString name = fileopen.GetPathName();
    CStringA namestr(name);
    ifstream file;
    file.open((const char*)namestr, 2);
    ...
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Имя файла видимо невалидное. Что в `name`-то находится? Вообще, отладчик запускать надо и смотреть. Постарайтесь приводить пример в виде [mcve].

Comment: Поверьте включение в файл ресурсов стандартных ресурсов, например afxres.rc. Возможно не найдено какое то сообщение.

Comment: Хорошо, понял, спасибо всем!